# Capture Original URL's GET / POST values?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm testing something. I would like to redirect my website (http://mywebsite.com) to a Landing Page (http://landingpage.com) ONLY when I pass a GET value. For example: id=23. So when it exists the page redirects.

My questions is that is there any script with the I can capture the list where I got redirected? I want the full link, like: http://mywebsite.com/index.php?id=23

Is there any possibility to capture that?

Also is there any possiblity to do the same with POST and capture that POST value on the Landing Page?

Comment: Pass it in the redirect. Make the URL you redirect to as `http://landingpage.com/?refer=http://mywebsite.com/index.php?id=23` (of course it needs URL encoded) and just get the `$_POST["refer"]`

Comment: Is there any other way? I'm just trying to figure out if someone else can detect that they got redirected from that GET/POST value.

Comment: They can see referrer and notice the GET value in it, not the POST though

Comment: How can they get the GET value?

Comment: because if you put a link on your webpage `http://www.example.com/?id=23` to my webpage `http://www.example2.com` then my webpage can see referrer and see your complete url. It will not always be set but most of the times it will work

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how can I capture the full URL?

Comment: @hek2mgl Your answer gave me some weird thing, but not the GET value.

Comment: @user1406071 Not willing to help anymore after that stupid downvotes. good night

Comment: I haven't downvoted you, basically I couldn't as I don't have enough rep..

Comment: others have done (for the correct answer) .. ok, willing again :) So, your problem is that you want to log the url a user *types in browser* to enter your page, yes?

Comment: I actually want to get the full address of the redirection page and I'd like to capture that on the landng page. I'd want what Hanky Panky said.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the data in a session variable? All you have to do is start the session again on the redirected page, and retrieve the session variables there.

Tutorial if you're not already aware of it: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

For example, on mywebsite.com:

```
session_start();

if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $_SESSION['url'] = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
}
```

on landingpage.com:

```
session_start();

$url = $_SESSION['url'] . '?id=' . $_SESSION['id'];
echo $url;
```

Although pretty sure this won't work if the pages are stored on two different servers, so I may be misunderstanding the question. If it's between servers, you could use a cookie instead.

Answer (score 0):

FOR GET:

You can simply attach `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to the landingpage:

```
<?php
$get = ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? "?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']: "";
$url = 'http://landingpage.com'.$get;
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

FOR POST: use CURL

```
if($_POST){
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://landingpage.com",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $_POST,
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig)
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: I actually want to detect from WHERE did the traffic came from.

Comment: the traffic might come from both: for example you can send POST to page.php?id=2 at this case both GET and POST are there, so, you can check both at same time